# How do I serve old xml sitemap after domain swap via nginx config

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I've recently swapped the domain extension of a site from .xyz to .com and I'm using a rule in my nginx config to 301 traffic from the old domain to the new one.

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name example.xyz www.example.xyz;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
  }
```

However I want to continue serving a sitemap at example.xyz/sitemap.xml

Is there a rule I can implement which will take preference over the 301 just for a single location? The sitemap can be a static file so I can use an alias but not sure how to stop the 301 taken effect for just that url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `return` statement into a `location /` block. Then you can add a `location =` block to match a single URI. For example:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name example.xyz www.example.xyz;

    location / {
        return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }
    location = /sitemap.xml {
        root /path/to/enclosing/directory;
    }
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: Thanks Richard! Would this configuration apply the 301 to all urls except "/sitemap.xml"?

So for example would "example.xyz/some-random-page" still get redirected to "example.com/some-random-page"

Comment: @user1803975 Yes - all URIs except the one matched by the `location =` block.